# the enqueue call method of retrofit didn't work

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm learning retrofit lately and I saw a video from youtube. I copied all the codes that I've seen in that video but my code didn't work at all. Nothing happens after I play the app in avd. no errors no exceptions and no logs . Do you know why ??

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txtResult ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtResult = findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
    Call<List<Post>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPosts();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
            Log.e("MAIN ACTIVITY","AAA");

            if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                txtResult.setText("Code : " + response.code());
                return;
            }
            List<Post> posts = response.body();
            Log.e("MAIN ACTIVITY","BBB");

            for(Post item : posts){
                String content = "";
                content = content.concat("Id : " + item.getId());
                content = content.concat("User Id : " + item.getUserId());
                content = content.concat("Title : " + item.getTitle());
                content = content.concat("Text : " + item.getText());
                txtResult.append(content);
                Log.e("MAIN ACTIVITY","CCC");

            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
            txtResult.setText(t.getMessage());
            Log.e("MAIN ACTIVITY","DDD");

        }
    });
}
```

}

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

@GET("posts")
Call<List<Post>> getPosts();
```

}

I use 4 log.e in my code but non of them work

**Update**

I think it's because of that I tried to run in android api 29. It runs well in android oreo without any problem but apparently in android 10 we just can fetch imformation from website that has ssl certificate otherwise we hit with Network security config error. Is it right ?

Comment: Did you add internet permission to the manifest? Also, add JsonPlaceHolderApi.class code to the question. Also, Log.e usually used for error and exception, use Log.d or Log.i instead

Comment: @Alex.Marinovskiy I add JsonPlaceHlderApi.
Yes I added internet permission . I use log.e because the font color of e is red and i can find it easily :)